# how to input upcoming missing year data using python

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I have monthly and daily weather data which starts from 1981 to 2018 but I want to have data for  2019 and 2020 based on the previous years . how can I do/ get data for 2019 and 2020 that using python

Comment: If it were possible to get reasonable data this way, weather forecasts would be much more reliable.

Comment: Either scrap it from web, or forecast it using any time-series model. eg: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/

Comment: Do you want to do projections? Please do share a sample of your data (not screenshot).

Comment: Check this out! This is how to do what you're after: https://jovian.ai/piero-paialunga/machinelearningclimatechange/v/1?utm_source=embed#C2